# Need a Way Around PHP Escaping \n

Tags: php

I'm making an install script that dynamically creates an index page for my site.
Here is the top portion of my script, up until the error:
the line: use menu_manager\navigation\navigation;

```
$file = '../index.php';
if($handle = fopen($file, 'w')){
    $content = "<?php
ob_start();
 header(\"Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0\");
 header(\"Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0\", false);
 header(\"Pragma: no-cache\");

 require_once('inc/functions.php');
 require_once('lib/menu_manager/autoLoader.php');
 use menu_manager\database\database;
 use menu_manager\pagination\pagination;
 use menu_manager\menu\MenuItem;
 use menu_manager\menu\menu;
 use menu_manager\page\page;
 use menu_manager\navigation\navigation;
```

When I run my script , This is how the actual index file ends up:

```
use menu_manager
avigation
avigation;
```

Is there a way to escape the \n in \navigation\navigation so that it does't think I want a new line?
Thanks

Comment: escape a "\" with "\\"

Comment: `\\navigation\\navigation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use single quotes instead of double quotes. `\n` won't be interpolated when in single quotes.
2. Use [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax (since PHP 5.3.0)
3. Escape the `\` in `\n` with another `\`. ie. `\\n`.

Comment: Well that was simple enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` characters with another `\` character. See the use statements below.

```
$file = '../index.php';
if($handle = fopen($file, 'w')){
    $content = "<?php
ob_start();
 header(\"Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0\");
 header(\"Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0\", false);
 header(\"Pragma: no-cache\");

 require_once('inc/functions.php');
 require_once('lib/menu_manager/autoLoader.php');
 use menu_manager\\database\\database;
 use menu_manager\\pagination\\pagination;
 use menu_manager\\menu\\MenuItem;
 use menu_manager\\menu\\menu;
 use menu_manager\\page\\page;
 use menu_manager\\navigation\\navigation;
```